How can I add analogRead to optiboot bootloader for ATmega2560?
I have a custom PCB with ATmega2560. I use optiboot as bootloader and I made some changes.
I allready enter in bootloader if soft reset was done.
Now I want to enter in bootloader if the 5V pin is HIGH and if analogRead(pinBattery)<100.
So if I don't have battery in and I plug the charger to enter in bootloader.
Just to have an alternative emergency method to enter in bootloader if firmware update fails and I cannot cause a soft reset.
But I cannot implement the analog read in optiboot.
My battery pin is PF1.
My 5v pin is PF3.
#define BATTERY_PIN 1 // Analog pin for reading battery voltage (PF1)
#define FIVEV_PIN 3   // Digital pin connected to 5V line (PF3)

The PCB is running at 8Mhz with external crystal.
The circuit runs at 3.3V
The code I tried for analog init is this.
    // Configure pins
DDRF &= ~(1 << BATTERY_PIN); // Set battery pin as input
DDRF &= ~(1 << FIVEV_PIN);    // Set 5V pin as input
int batteryVoltage = readBatteryVoltage();

and the readbatteryvoltage is this
int readBatteryVoltage() {
    // Read analog value from battery pin
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN); // Enable ADC
    ADMUX = (0 << REFS1) | (1 << REFS0) | BATTERY_PIN; // Select AVCC as reference, set battery pin as input
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC); // Start conversion
    while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC)); // Wait for conversion to complete
    return ADC; // Return ADC value
}

The if that will enter in bootloader
ch = MCUSR;
if ((ch & _BV(WDRF)) || ((PINF & (1 << PF3)) && (batteryVoltage<100)))  {


I have checked the readings using my main program.
Arduino analogRead(BATTERY_PIN) returns 0 if there is no battery and digitalRead returns 1. These conditions are met as soon as the program starts.
I cannot use digitalRead(BATTERY_PIN) because it returns 0 with a low battery.
There is no other way, adding a button etc.
I do not have deep knowledge and I wrote the above lines with help from AI.
I have space in bootloader. A lot.
I also tried to include Arduino.h but it didn't work either.
Thank you in advance.

learn how to read ADC without Arduino. you can test it in a sketch before you use it in the bootloader.

This worked for me. I post it here in case someone needs it. I reed from channel 1 directly. I call InitADC and then I can get the analog read for channel 1 with ReadADC1(). Mega2560 running at 8Mhz and 3.3V.
uint16_t ReadADC1(){
// Select ADC channel 1 (corresponding to PF1)
ADMUX = (ADMUX & 0xF0) | 0x01;

// Start single conversion mode
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);

// Wait until ADC conversion is complete
while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC));

// Read ADC result (combine ADCL and ADCH)
uint16_t adcResult = ADCL; // Read ADCL first (important!)
adcResult |= (ADCH << 8); // Combine ADCL and ADCH

return adcResult;

void InitADC(){
// Select Vref=AVcc
ADMUX |= (1<<REFS0);
//set prescaller to 128 and enable ADC 
ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0)|(1<<ADEN);    

}
